# How can I update this Runge-Kutta code for second order ODEs?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I've written a piece of FORTRAN code that solves first order differential equations, for example the one that is in the function at the momement. However, I want to use it for second order ODES (and eventually 2nd order coupled ODEs), but I'm struggling to adapt it. Here's the code:

```
program rungekutta
implicit none
integer :: istat
real(8)::a,b,h,y_0,t

  write(*,*)"Enter interval a,b, step-size h and y_0"
  read(*,*)a,b,h,y_0
  open(unit=1, file="rungekutta.dat",status='replace', iostat=istat)
  if (istat .ne. 0) stop 'error opening rungekutta.dat'
  call RungeKuttaSub(y_0,a,b,h)
  close(1)

contains
  subroutine RungeKuttaSub(y_0,a,b,h)
  implicit none
  real(8), intent(inout)::a,h,b, y_0
  real(8):: y,t, F_1, F_2, F_3, F_4

    t=a
    y=y_0
    do while(t<=b)
      F_1=h*f(y,t)
      F_2=h*f(y+(1d0/2d0)*F_1, t+h*(1d0/2d0))
      F_3=h*f(y+(1d0/2d0)*F_2, t+h*(1d0/2d0))
      F_4=h*f(y+F_3,t+h)
      y=y+(F_1+2d0*F_2+2d0*F_3+F_4)/6d0
      write(1,*)t, y
      t=t+h
    end do
  end subroutine

  function f(y,t)
  implicit none
  real(8)::f,y,t,pi

    pi=acos(-1d0)
    f=-y+sin(pi*2d0*t)
  end function
end program
```

So as you can see the differential in the function at the moment is `y'(t) = -y(t) + sin(2*pi*t)`. How can I update this for 2nd order ODEs?

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a mathematical and not a programming problem. Do you know the mathematics of it? BTW `real(8)` is ugly, not portable and does not mean universally 8 bytes.

Comment: Thanks, i've upated it to `integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15,300)` now. I'm fairly sure I know the mathematics, but one of my issues with this is writing down a second order ODE as a function to begin with.

Comment: You know how to transform the 2nd order equation into a 1st order system? And how to implement vector addition and scalar multiplication? Btw. what do you have against 0.5, do you expect your code will be used on a ternary computer where that number is not exactly representable?

Comment: @LutzL If that was the only thing  making the code ugly and hard to read all would be nice. But it is really ugly as a whole. No indentation, no spaces  in expressions, no empty lines... It is really bad. But I still think OP's problem is in mathematics, not in programming. He claims it is not the case, but didn't demonstrate it in any way.

Comment: You might get inspiration on interfaces and implementation from other online sources such as https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/rk4/rk4.f90